# Как создать несколько cookie разом?

Tags: javascript

```
document.cookie = 'name=' + name + '; path=/;';
document.cookie = 'age=' + age + '; path=/;';
document.cookie = 'weight=' + weight + '; path=/;';
```

Comment: Ну вот, создали.

Comment: Просто проблема в том, что в safari сохраняется почему-то только weight, а первые 2 не сохраняются. Хотя переменные не пустые, проверял.

Comment: Все, я понял, safari не сохраняет в кукисы русские буквы...

Comment: Можешь написать это как ответ))